# TextView content is being cut off at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, display, spacing

in my app, the TextView specified as R.id.text3 does cut off its content with half of a line being shown sometimes. Additionally, ellipsize is not working either. From the layout, do you see what I have to add so the Text is letting out the cut off line and (in the best case) ellipsizing at the end too?

If you might need my CursorAdapter code, please feel free to ask for it! I am by the way also defining a padding on the "linearLayout" to match the navigation bar.

[image: This is how it looks.]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:airbnb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:id="@+id/baseRelativeLayout"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:minHeight="80dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/entry_img_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/entry_img_size"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.Daily.MediumComponent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/titleLinearLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_icon"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textColor="?attr/contentColor"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                android:textColor="?attr/contentColor"
                android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/favorite_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            airbnb:lottie_fileName="star.json"
            airbnb:lottie_scale="0.3"
            airbnb:lottie_autoPlay="false"
            airbnb:lottie_loop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="?attr/contentColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hello, Florent Anders can you explain what you want exactly. can u share ur design Screen short?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your LinearLayout(linearLayout) inside a `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <....
              ....>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: My shared layout is part of a CursorAdapter and a full-screen ListView. A scrollview inside a ListView is not the solution for me, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

for ellipsize, try to add android:maxlines.
for the cut line, you need to use a scrollview i think.

Comment: The layout shared is part of a CursorAdapter and a full-screen ListView. Maxlines and ScrollView is not a solution for me, but thanks :)